# a demo application on rhoConnect while developing rhodes application

Tags: rhodes

hi I am new to  Rhodes application .We are facing problem in how to start rhoConnect. can u please share me the  demo application.

Please help.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation for [**RhoConnect**](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhoconnect/tutorial). It even has sample example for the SourceAdapters. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Watch the video tutorial link below, It will helpful to you.

```
 Beginning Rhodes     http://vimeo.com/31755872 
 Beginning Rhoconnect http://vimeo.com/31983806
 Introducing Rhoconnect http://vimeo.com/28789274
```